# remove button form scrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I added one UIScrollView in my project... and I added 10 more button "fieldButton" once, then the same UIScrollView I want add other 5 button. it I try to do this first added 10 button also coming in the scrollview .. how to remove first added 10 button before adding other item. in the same scrollview...

```
if(a == 1){
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        UIButton *fieldButton_area = [[Mos_component alloc]getComboButton:title       andFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 180, 40)];

        [fieldButton_area addSubview:cid];
        [fieldButton_area addTarget:self action:@selector(get_Area:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [state_scroll addSubview:fieldButton_area];
   }
}
else{
    UIButton *fieldButton_state = [[Mos_component alloc]getComboButton:title andFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 180, 40)];
    [fieldButton_state addSubview:cid];
    [fieldButton_state addTarget:self action:@selector(get_Area:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [state_scroll addSubview:fieldButton_state];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to clear your scrollview (i.e. remove all its subviews) then you can do that following way:

```
for (UIView* subView in [state_scroll subviews])
    [subView removeFromSuperView];
```

If you want to remove some specific views you can check its types:

```
for (UIView* subView in [state_scroll subviews])
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[Mos_component class]]) // remove Mos_components only
        [subView removeFromSuperView];
```

You can also assign tag property to you views and remove them following way:

```
 [[fieldButton_area viewWithTag:yourTag] removeFromSuperView];
```

Also note that you must release your buttons somewhere or you will get memory leak.

Comment: UIView is the problem..

can we use here Nssarry instead of UIview ?. then remove each one..tr ?

Comment: now it is working ... fine ... thank you very much dear Vladimir.
i have one doubt on this for loop. and how to access subView 
the UIButton object... pls help

then.. i removed it take it out to one nsarray then remove one by one

Answer (score 0):

You could also try animating the button(s) off of the screen or set the `alpha`'s to 0 then add the new `UIButton`'s to the view. This may use more memory, but in some cases look better.

```
[UIView BeginAnimation];
// set time and speed here

// Perform animation here

[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector /* here call the method for the new button's animation into the view*/];

[UIView CommitAnimations];
// Then set the button's enabled property to NO
button.enabled = NO;
```

I hope this is of some assistance